# I know it's painful, but could someone check my math?

Tags: discussion

regarding [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51759/harmonic-distortion-of-sine-signal-plotting-resulting-spectrum/51763#51763).

it also seems to me that this result should have been obtained and published somewhere or documented in a book somewhere, but i dunno where.  if someone knows of a reference, i would love to know about it.

TIA.

Comment: right away, i think [i am informed of a big error](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908000/whats-the-easiest-most-concise-way-to-prove-this-simple-swapping-of-order-o) in the swapping of the summation order.

Comment: As the commentor of (math.se) **dxiv** stated, unless the matrix is symmetric; $A = A^{T}$, the equality wont hold. Cause the left side is summing the lower triangular elements while the right side is summing the upper triangular elements. This assumes that for the element $a_{nk}$, $n$ stands for rows and $k$ stands for $columns$.

Comment: @Fat32, i think i groked this upper and lower triangle thing and i fixed the limits in my summations.  i hope it's right now, but i would still like someone else to verify.

Comment: I just checked it (on the surface) and it seems ok.

Comment: thank you @Fat32